# Building BouncyCastle 1.47 jar from source

Tags: java, build, jar, bouncycastle

So, I'm wanting to create a new jar of BouncyCastle 1.47 that isn't an OSGi jar.  I have downloaded the source from their [site](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) (the bcprov-jdk15on-147.tar.gz file under "JCE with provider and lightweight API" for JDK1.5-1.7), but when I extract it and the source, I see no build scripts.  Looking at their wiki, they say that it should be a simple case of using ant.

Has anyone done this before, and can show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What is the issue with OSGi jar? You should be able to use it as "normal" jar as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An OSGI [bundle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi#Bundles) is simply a jar file with additional metadata in the `MANIFEST.MF`. I would expect you to be able to use it as a vanilla jar file.